# Rails: uninitialized constant Class::MyModule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a Rails app, and my tests are throwing an error indicating that a class is undefined. The class in question is defined at `lib/vegetable/yam.rb`, which contains (in part):

```
class Vegetable::Yam
  def self.eat
    "tasty"
  end
end
```

I'm trying to use that `eat` method in a model `app/models/user.rb`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def phrase
    Vegetable::Yam.eat
  end
end
```

In the Rails console, if I call the `.phrase` method on a User instance, I get "tasty" as expected. However, my tests throw:

```
Failure/Error: Vegetable::Yam.eat
     
     NameError:
       uninitialized constant #<Class:0x000000012caaab90>::Vegetable
```

Does anyone know why that would be or how I can resolve it? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `eat` is an instance method. Yet you're calling it on the class `Vegetable::Yam`. If you intended to write a class method you forgot `self`.

Comment: Also "The module in question is defined at lib/vegetable/yam.rb" - yet you're defining a class. And the way that you're defining it with the scope resoltion operator `::` instead of explicit nesting will raise an error unless the `Vegetable` module is already defined. See https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition

Comment: Hmm, I can load `lib/yeet/deet.rb` in the Rails console without issue `Yeet::Deet`. I'm on Rails 5.2

Comment: Thats because Rails uses autoloading in development and the old autoloader monkeys with Object#const_missing thus hiding the issue. In the test environment rails eager loads all the classes at startup which doesn't guarentee that `Vegetable` is loaded before this file. You would get the same issue in production. Define your namespaces correctly and the problem goes away. See https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants_classic_mode.html#nesting-and-qualified-constants

Comment: `module Vegetable; class Yam; ... end; end`

Comment: Rails is savage. Is it a terrible idea to just `require "#{Rails.root}/lib/vegetable/yam"` inside of `user.rb`?

Comment: It depends. Since I'm guessing that you added `lib` to the autoloading roots its a pretty bad idea. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants_classic_mode.html#autoloading-and-require

Comment: Do the autoloading roots descend recursively through subdirectories?

Comment: Yes. A root is where the autoloader will look for top level constants. It will then look for `Foo::Bar` in `/lib/foo/bar.rb` and all the other roots.